# Request validation with GET method isn't working in Laravel 8 - Recaptcha

Tags: laravel, validation, get, recaptcha, laravel-8

I am trying to integrate recaptcha to a query form, where the user enters only one piece of data and it returns the result that is extracted from the database.

I'm using
https://github.com/anhskohbo/no-captcha

But a validation is needed from the controller
Something like this appears in your documentation

```
$validate = Validator::make(Input::all(), [
    'g-recaptcha-response' => 'required|captcha'
]);
```

Adjusted it for Laravel 8
But since I have my form in a GET method, I cannot use the validations, so I use your wisdom to be able to achieve the integration with recaptcha

This is my ListadoRequest

```
 <?php
    namespace App\Http\Requests; 
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
    
    class ListadoRequest extends FormRequest
    {
        public function authorize()
        {
            return true;
        }
        public function rules()
        {
            return [
                'texto' => 'required',
                'g-recaptcha-response' => 'required|captcha',
            ];
        }
    }
```

This is my controller:

```
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    use App\Models\Listado;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use App\Http\Requests\ListadoRequest;
    
    class ListadoController extends Controller
    {
        public function index(ListadoRequest $request){
    
         $validated = $request->validated();
         //other code
}
```

This is my web.php

```
Route::get('/busqueda', [ListadoController::class, 'index'])->name('busqueda');
```

**When I try to enter the form it does not enter and stays on the main page**

If I remove the validation line and change `ListadoRequest` to `Request` I access my form but obviously the captcha is a lie because it is not required

[image]

Update
My view

```
<form action="{{route('busqueda')}}" method="get">
        <input type = "text" class="form-control" name="texto" value="{{$texto}}" >
        <br>
        {!! NoCaptcha::display() !!}
        <input type=submit class="btn btn-primary" value= "Buscar">
    </form>
```

Help pls :(

Comment: The captcha is meant to "protect" the target of a form submission. Here you're validating at what seems to be the source

Comment: I did not understand :(

Comment: Which route generates your view ? Also what is your form `action=` and `method=`  values and which route do they correspond to?

Comment: oh ok I did an update and add the view